# InvalidAuthenticationToken when uploading file to OneDrive

Tags: bash, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file to OneDrive using the following code:

```
$graph_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/filename:/createUploadSession';
$file = file_get_contents('logo.jpeg');
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: json',
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "Authorization: bearer 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",
    "Content-Length: ".filesize('logo.jpeg'),
];

$ch = curl_init($graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graph_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{}');
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

The result, however, is the always the following error:

```
"error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "bab6035c-17c5-45ea-99ac-7c809e446ca2",
        "date": "2018-12-22T09:42:03"
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you obtaining the token? The one you've included in your example is not a valid JWT token.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems like your token is incorrect. So step 1 is verify the token is correct. You can do that by copying your token and pasting it on the website Microsoft created specifically for this job. https://jwt.ms

Secondly as the microsoft documentation describes you have 2 ways of uploading a file to onedrive.

1. **Direct upload (only for small files)** [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0)
2. **Through a upload session**, [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0)

You're trying to do a direct upload to the `CreateUploadSession` endpoint. 
The first way works (for small files) by uploading the file to the `/content` endpoint, but that is just a file only upload. So no content headers with `json` in them.

The second way works by creating an upload sessions (that responds with some json) and then do a second request for uploading the file to the endpoint you got from the url.

The documentation on these things are quite clear, and I think you're using PHP, so it should be easy to mimic the provided curl requests with php.